# How to create a SQL query for the below scenario

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake SQL, but I guess this can be solved by any sql. So I have data like this:

```
RA_MEMBER_ID    YEAR    QUARTER MONTH   Monthly_TOTAL_PURCHASE  CATEGORY
1000             2020      1     1          105                   CAT10
1000             2020      1     1          57                    CAT13
1000             2020      1     2          107                   CAT10
1000             2020      1     2          59                    CAT13
1000             2020      1     3          109                   CAT11
1000             2020      1     3          61                    CAT14
1000             2020      2     4          111                   CAT11
1000             2020      2     4          63                    CAT14
1000             2020      2     5          113                   CAT12
1000             2020      2     5          65                    CAT15
1000             2020      2     6          115                   CAT12
1000             2020      2     6          67                    CAT15
```

And I need data like this:

```
RA_MEMBER_ID    YEAR    QUARTER MONTH   Monthly_TOTAL_PURCHASE  CATEGORY    Monthly_rank    Quarterly_Total_purchase    Quarter_category    Quarter_rank    Yearly_Total_purchase   Yearly_category Yearly_rank
1000            2020         1    1        105                    CAT10          1                105                         CAT10              1                105                   CAT10            1
1000            2020         1    1        57                     CAT13          2                57                          CAT13              2                57                    CAT13            2
1000            2020         1    2        107                    CAT10          1                212                         CAT10              1                212                   CAT10            1
1000            2020         1    2        59                     CAT13          2                116                         CAT13              2                116                   CAT13            2
1000            2020         1    3        109                    CAT11          1                212                         CAT10              1                212                   CAT10            1
1000            2020         1    3        61                     CAT14          2                116                         CAT13              2                116                   CAT13            2
1000            2020         2    4        111                    CAT11          1                111                         CAT11              1                212                   CAT10            1
1000            2020         2    4        63                     CAT14          2                63                          CAT14              2                124                   CAT14            2
1000            2020         2    5        113                    CAT12          1                113                         CAT12              1                212                   CAT10            1
1000            2020         2    5        65                     CAT15          2                65                          CAT15              2                124                   CAT14            2
1000            2020         2    6        115                    CAT12          1                228                         CAT12              1                228                   CAT12            1
1000            2020         2    6        67                     CAT15          2                132                         CAT15              2                132                   CAT15            2
```

So basically, I have the top two categories by purchase amount for the first 6 months. I need the same for quarterly based on which month of the quarter it is. So let's say it is February, then the top 2 categories and amounts should be calculated based on both January and February. For March we have to get the quarter data by taking all three months. From April it will be the same as monthly rank, for May again calculate based on April and May. Similarly for Yearly also.
I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to give me what I want.
The solution should be generic enough because there can be many other months and years.
I really need help in this.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70029519/edit) your question to include the source data - as text, not a screen shot - and include any queries you've attempted to write explaining why you don't think they work.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning I have uploaded the excel file. I have tried coming up with a solution but my tries aren't even worth mentioning. Basically I am not able to even comprehend how to approach the solution to this. :)

Comment: A linked Excel file is not the same thing as text pasted into the question. StackOverflow questions and answers are meant to be self-contained. No security-conscious person is going to download your Excel file.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Done. :)

Comment: SO isn't a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you've encountered, include the relevant portions of your code or SQL in the form of a [mre], and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if below is what you are after. I assume that everything is category based:

```
create or replace table test (
    ra_member_id int, 
    year int, 
    quarter int, 
    month int, 
    monthly_purchase int, 
    category varchar
);

insert into test values 
(1000, 2020, 1,1, 105, 'cat10'),
(1000, 2020, 1,1, 57, 'cat13'),
(1000, 2020, 1,2, 107, 'cat10'),
(1000, 2020, 1,2, 59, 'cat13'),
(1000, 2020, 1,3, 109, 'cat11'),
(1000, 2020, 1,3, 61, 'cat14'),
(1000, 2020, 2,4, 111, 'cat11'),
(1000, 2020, 2,4, 63, 'cat14'),
(1000, 2020, 2,5, 113, 'cat12'),
(1000, 2020, 2,5, 65, 'cat15'),
(1000, 2020, 2,6, 115, 'cat12'),
(1000, 2020, 2,6, 67, 'cat15');

WITH BASE as (
    select  
        RA_MEMBER_ID,
        YEAR,
        QUARTER,
        MONTH,
        CATEGORY,
        MONTHLY_PURCHASE,
        LAG(MONTHLY_PURCHASE) OVER (PARTITION BY QUARTER, CATEGORY ORDER BY MONTH) AS QUARTERLY_PURCHASE_LAG,
        IFNULL(QUARTERLY_PURCHASE_LAG, 0)  + MONTHLY_PURCHASE AS QUARTERLY_PURCHASE,
        LAG(MONTHLY_PURCHASE) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR, CATEGORY ORDER BY MONTH) AS YEARLY_PURCHASE_LAG,
        IFNULL(YEARLY_PURCHASE_LAG, 0)  + MONTHLY_PURCHASE AS YEARLY_PURCHASE
    FROM 
        TEST
),
BASE_RANK AS (
    SELECT 
        RA_MEMBER_ID,
        YEAR,
        QUARTER,
        MONTH,
        CATEGORY,
        MONTHLY_PURCHASE,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH ORDER BY MONTHLY_PURCHASE DESC) as MONTHLY_RANK,
        QUARTERLY_PURCHASE,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY QUARTER ORDER BY QUARTERLY_PURCHASE DESC) as QUARTERLY_RANK,
        YEARLY_PURCHASE,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR ORDER BY YEARLY_PURCHASE DESC) as YEARLY_RANK
    FROM BASE
),
MAIN AS (
    SELECT 
        RA_MEMBER_ID,
        YEAR,
        QUARTER,
        MONTH,
        CATEGORY,
        MONTHLY_PURCHASE,
        MONTHLY_RANK,
        QUARTERLY_PURCHASE,
        QUARTERLY_RANK,
        YEARLY_PURCHASE,
        YEARLY_RANK
    FROM BASE_RANK
)
SELECT * FROM MAIN
ORDER BY YEAR, QUARTER, MONTH
;
```

Result:

```
+--------------+------+---------+-------+----------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+
| RA_MEMBER_ID | YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | CATEGORY | MONTHLY_PURCHASE | MONTHLY_RANK | QUARTERLY_PURCHASE | QUARTERLY_RANK | YEARLY_PURCHASE | YEARLY_RANK |
|--------------+------+---------+-------+----------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------|
|         1000 | 2020 |       1 |     1 | cat10    |              105 |            1 |                105 |              4 |             105 |           9 |
|         1000 | 2020 |       1 |     1 | cat13    |               57 |            2 |                 57 |              6 |              57 |          12 |
|         1000 | 2020 |       1 |     2 | cat10    |              107 |            1 |                212 |              1 |             212 |           3 |
|         1000 | 2020 |       1 |     2 | cat13    |               59 |            2 |                116 |              2 |             116 |           6 |
|         1000 | 2020 |       1 |     3 | cat11    |              109 |            1 |                109 |              3 |             109 |           8 |
|         1000 | 2020 |       1 |     3 | cat14    |               61 |            2 |                 61 |              5 |              61 |          11 |
|         1000 | 2020 |       2 |     4 | cat11    |              111 |            1 |                111 |              4 |             220 |           2 |
|         1000 | 2020 |       2 |     4 | cat14    |               63 |            2 |                 63 |              6 |             124 |           5 |
|         1000 | 2020 |       2 |     5 | cat12    |              113 |            1 |                113 |              3 |             113 |           7 |
|         1000 | 2020 |       2 |     5 | cat15    |               65 |            2 |                 65 |              5 |              65 |          10 |
|         1000 | 2020 |       2 |     6 | cat12    |              115 |            1 |                228 |              1 |             228 |           1 |
|         1000 | 2020 |       2 |     6 | cat15    |               67 |            2 |                132 |              2 |             132 |           4 |
+--------------+------+---------+-------+----------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But this is not what I am looking for. I want Quarterly ranking of 1 and 2 only based on what the previous rows in that quarter has.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't fully understand the requirement.